# Is there a react method to dynamically add items from an array to a div in a custom pattern

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using a div that contains an image below which rows are added with products in them. The product gallery must look like a pyramid so below the image there will be three product rows each containing one, two and three products (each product being a custom rfce), respectively.

Illustration:

img

div1 => product

div2 => product product

div3 => product product product

I used a function that renders a string with all the desired attributes and tried using parse (from html-react-parse) to convert the string to html tags but this method seems slightly unprofessional in addition to which upon attempting to parse the string (which was formatted correctly), I am getting an error.
How can I rectify this, and is there a better method I can use?

string generation method:

```
const getProducts = () => {
    var cur = 0
    var gallery = ``
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var prods = ``
        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            const product = products[cur++]
            // <Product /> is a custom rfce.
            prods +=    `<Product
                            id = ${product.id}
                            pname = ${product.pname}
                            price = ${product.price}
                            rating = ${product.rating}
                            pic = ${product.pic}
                            altPic = ${product.altPic}           
                        />`
        }
        gallery += `<div className = 'product_row'>
                        ${prods}
                    </div>`
    }
    return ({gallery})
}
```

method call:

```
return (
...
    <div className = 'product_container'>
    <img src = {banner} alt = 'banner' />
    {parse(getProducts())}
</div>
...
```

)

the string is displayed just fine in the body before using parse but upon using it I get the following error after the line `const product = products[cur++]` in `getProducts()`:

`TypeError: product is undefined`

Even if I get parse to work, I'd like to use another method as I'm sure there is a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the shape (JSX) you want, I would just hardcode the array chunks. Create a function to render an array into a row, and use the utility for each row, slicing the `products` state into sub-arrays to be rendered into the rows.

[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` (`end` not included)
> where `start` and `end` represent the index of items in that array. The
> original array will not be modified.

```
const renderRow = row => (
  <div className='product_row'>
    {row.map(product => (
      <Product
        key={product.id}
        id={product.id}
        pname={product.pname}
        price={product.price}
        rating={product.rating}
        pic={product.pic}
        altPic={product.altPic}           
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);


return (
  ...
  <div className = 'product_container'>
    <img src={banner} alt='banner' />
    {renderRow(products.slice(0,1))}
    {renderRow(products.slice(1,3))}
    {renderRow(products.slice(3,6))}
  </div>
  ...
);
```

Comment: The shape was provided just to help get my point across. ^This code generates a new row for every product/doesn't map multiple products to the same row. I could define the rows and then use your method (with the exception of the parent div being genrated in renderRow) to accomplish what I want but I wanted a dynamic alternative.
Thank you very much for the solution, though.

Comment: @Nrook301 Oh, shoot, you're right, let me fix that. Sorry about inverting that div. Can you clarify your comment about "dynamic alternative". Dynamic as in, you want to handle an arbitrary number of rows? Or an arbitrary row width? Something else?

Comment: Just adding labels and other stuff, I found what I was looking for. Thanks again!